# get the value of span inside a div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, html

How do I get the whole segment of Location Address including the address, city state and ZIP inside of a span which is inside another div in jquery?

```
<div class="EachLocation" style="width:225px;float:right;position:relative; border-bottom:1px dotted silver;">
    Munster Women's Center<br />
    <span class="LocationAddress">1455 Sycamore Blvd.<br>Munster,IN 42103</span>
    <br>(219) 232-7601<br><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Try the following

```
var text = $('div.EachLocation span.LocationAddress').text();
```

Note: If there is more than one set of DOM elements which matches that selector then the text returned will be the combined contents of all of them.

Answer (score 2):

How about?

```
$('.LocationAddress').text();
```

It doesn't matter where it's at in the DOM tree, unless you actually want to limit its scope to one parent or another. If you want to preserve the `<br/>` as well, use `.html()` instead of `.text()`.

**UPDATE**

So, in truth, you most likely want each `.EachLocation`'s address and not just the first. So it should really be something like:

```
$('.EachLocation').each(function(){
    $('.LocationAddress', this).text();
});
```

Comment: It will work, but it will also look for that class outside of the EachLocation container.

Comment: True, but it's actually not much more useful even then. See update.

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery:

`$('div.EachLocation span.LocationAddress').html()`

Comment: That will return the HTML vs. the text inside of it.  Hence they would end up with the `<br>` tag and the like.  I believe the OP wants only the text involved

Comment: I think you mean `$('div.EachLocation span.LocationAddress').text();`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do is to give `id` to the `span` and then get the `value` or `html` what ever is required for example if span `id` is set to `locationaddress`

```
$('#locationaddress').html();
```